# Amount of Composites That Share a factor with $n$

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function

Is there some way to use Euler's Totient function to represent the amount of odd composites that share a factor with integer $n$ less than $n$? For instance,

$n-\phi(n)$ represents the total amount of composites less than $n$ that share a factor with $n$. How might I reduce this to only the odd composites?

Comment: For odd numbers it's still $n-\phi(n)$. For $n=2^rp$ with $p$ prime and $r\ge 1$, it's $2^{r-1}$.

Comment: Can you use the prime counting function $\pi(n)$? If so, you might have to  adjust by $+1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is *even*, then no even number is relatively prime to $n,$ so the $n-\phi(n)$ numbers not-relatively-prime-to-n include the $n/2$ even numbers, so in that case, your number is:
$$n/2 - \phi(n).$$

If $n$ is *odd,* then the number of even numbers not-relatively-prime to $n$ is the same as the number of number $\leq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ not-relatively-prime to $n.$ Now the number of integers relatively prime to $n$ and less than or equal to $n/2$ is $\Phi(n, \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor),$ where $\Phi(n, x)$ is defined (see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88777/bound-the-error-in-estimating-a-relative-totient-function)) as
$$\Phi(n,x)=x-\sum_i\lfloor{x/{p_i}}\rfloor+\sum_{i \lt j}\lfloor x/{p_ip_j}\rfloor-\cdots+(-1)^{k}\lfloor x/{n}\rfloor,$$ and thus the number of even numbers not-relatively-prime-to-n equals 
$$E(n) = \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor - \Phi(n, \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor).$$ So, the number of *odd* non-relativel-prime integers is
$$n-\phi(n) - E(n).$$ I am not sure if you can simplify this further.

Comment: Can't you simplify $E(n)$ to $\sum_i\lfloor{x/{p_i}}\rfloor+\sum_{i \lt j}\lfloor x/{p_ip_j}\rfloor-\cdots+(-1)^{k}\lfloor x/{n}\rfloor$?

Comment: @LinusRastegar Indeed! I was wondering whether one can avoid alternating sums altogether ...

Comment: If $x = \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ I think there is a way to simplify $E(n)$ further because this means that $\Phi(n,x)$ can somehow be related the product of $1-\frac{1}{p_i}$, as the question you linked claimed with a simpler version of $\Phi$.

Comment: @LinusRastegar Yes, but it is not clear that there is a closed form. In fact, each $\lfloor \frac{x}{p_1 \dots p_k}\rfloor$ equals
$$\lfloor \frac{n}{2 p_1 \dots p_k}\rfloor,$$ but the trick is getting rid of the floors...

Comment: You could split the floors into two separate cases. $\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor$ could be rewritten as $\frac{n}{2}$ when $n$ is even and $\frac{n}{2} - 1$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: @LinusRastegar The $n$ even case is easy and dealt with in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I'm wondering whether that same concept could be applied to the floor of the numbers you have in the answer and comment you left.